# Freezing one page from time to time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I've got case when user wants to login and from time to time, the login page freezes (page is loading all the time) and nothing happens. The problem disappears when user open the app in “Incognito” mode in Chrome.  I observed the same situation happening sometimes in Incognito mode too however, when performing some internally tests. The only way to solve this situation when it happens is to clear all caches and delete all web browsing history. I've got this response from the server https://monosnap.com/file/jmEkKWaGelHYzTODq385choJ8pke3J

I thought it the problem could be in some docker images (some container/image overrider) but I've only one container so this is not the case.

Is it possible to set automatic data cleansing in Rails app that the user does not do this? I'm using Rails and Grape in this app.

Comment: Don't try to automatically clearing user cache, etc. It's a bad idea. You have to fix the real problem since it could cause some problems that you may not be seeing. Check the browser console and network tab using the dev tools. Check the rails server log, check with other browsers. You can disable caching opening dev tools, you can try removing one cookie at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the question. It looks tough. How are you authenticating the request(s)?

Comment: It's difficult to know what is the problem with these informations, but automatically clean the data is a dressing, you must fix the problem and not its consequences. Can you add your logs when the page freeze? Javascript errors in your dev tools console?